# grails errors on all commands

Tags: grails

I need to get grails working to compile asgard from netflix, but I seem to be hitting an issue that i have yet to find a solution for.

```
$  $GRAILS_HOME/bin/grails help

| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
| Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl
| Error         at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:45)
| Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:381)
| Error         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:377)
| Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:59)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:28)
| Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
| Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:252)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.establishProjectStructure(BuildSettings.groovy:1452)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.setBaseDir(BuildSettings.groovy:835)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings$setBaseDir.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.<init>(BuildSettings.groovy:774)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.<init>(BuildSettings.groovy:749)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:164)
| Error         ... 6 more


$  java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

The zip file for 2.1.1 is from the grails site and i have yet to find anything missing.  All grails commands are doing this.

Am i missing something?

Comment: I too am having the same problem, I am also using the same grails version 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Are you following asgard [reccomandation](https://github.com/Netflix/asgard/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)??

```
Run Sun/Oracle Java 6 on Linux or Mac
    Avoid Java 7
    Avoid OpenJDK
    Avoid Windows
    Yes, Asgard runs on Grails, and Grails runs on Java, and Java is supposed to be "run
 anywhere", except for the fact that Asgard users have reported incompatibility problems with 
Java 7, OpenJDK, and Windows. A future version of Asgard will be Java 7 compatible, and 
perhaps it will work with OpenJDK eventually. The Windows issue is less likely to get 
debugged by Netflix engineers, but if you figure it out feel free to send a pull request.
```

Comment: I should be.  I told grails that java_home is oracle 6 java.